# Can I set up variables for use in an apache configuration file?

Tags: variables, apache

I have a php webapp convention that I'd like to follow and a lot of setup for it is done in the apache configuration file.

Is there any way I can configure some strings that contain paths for multiple uses throughout the configuration file?

A dim example might be:

```
EnginePath = /opt/engine
AppPath = /opt/anapp

DocumentRoot [AppPath]/Public
CustomLog [AppPath]/Logs/Access.log combined

php_admin_value auto_prepend_file [EnginePath]/EngineBootstrap.php
```

As you can see, I have lots of opportunities to consolodate several repeted occurences of the system and app paths.  This would make it easier to keep the configuration files as generic as possible, requiring a change in app or engine location to be edited once.  Rather than several times per configuration file.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Related question: [Using variables in Apache config files to reduce duplication?](http://serverfault.com/questions/64656/using-variables-in-apache-config-files-to-reduce-duplication/64745#64745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible in apache configuration files.

However, what may be possible is for you to pre-process your httpd.conf file.  I've used this technique with other configuration files, and it should work.  For example, if you use php:

Save your httpd.conf.php

> `<?php
>
>      $EnginePath = '/opt/engine';
>
>      $AppPath = '/opt/anapp';
>
>   ?>`
>
> DocumentRoot `<?php echo $EnginePath; ?>`/Public
>   CustomLog `<?php echo $AppPath; ?>`/Logs/Access.log combined
>
> php_admin_value auto_prepend_file `<?php echo $EnginePath; ?>`/EngineBootstrap.php

When you want to change your config, call:

> php httpd.conf.php > httpd.conf

This means you have to regenerate your conf file every time you want to make a change, but that can also be automated via some quick shell scripting.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question correctly : it is possible to define variables. See below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Define

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#define

or mod_macro

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/mod/mod_macro.html